# pack error with google chrome extention

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My extension works well under the dev mode,but when i want to pack it this time ,there comes an error which said:"Manifest file missing or unreadable", i don't know why!

```
{
"name": "DoTask",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "DoTaskv2个人任务管理系统--谷歌浏览器插件",
"options_page": "option.html",
"icons": { "16": "favicon.ico", "32": "favicon.ico", "128": "favicon.ico"},
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "favicon.ico",
    "popup": "popup.html"
    },
"permissions": [
     "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: If you post your manifest.json someone might be able to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The manifest file **must be named manifest.json** (notice: *json* not *js*),  **must be in the root** of the zip file or directory and it also **must be saved as UTF-8**.